# how to solve an optimization problems in image processing via Conjugate Gradient?

Tags: python, image, matlab, optimization, gradient

I am trying to solve the following minimization problem, but I don't know how to solve it and program it in matlab or python. I really appreciate it if you could help me.

```
Î : output image
I : input image
G : an guiding image

Î = argmin ||Î -  I ||^2 + ||gradient(Î) - gradient(G)||^2
```

to find an image (`Î`) which is as close as possible to I in appearance and its gradient is as close as possible to gradient of `G`.
Specifically I am interested in solving the energy minimization in the paper

[link](http://grail.cs.washington.edu/projects/gradientshop/demos/gs_paper_TOG_2009.pdf)

in part 3 and 3.1 in equation 1,2 and 3 which they have mentioned they have solved it via conjugate gradient method.
there is no constrained rather than that `Î` pixels are [0,255]. I don't have any idea how to solve it numerically or analytically. I know matlab c++ python.
best

Comment: There are tons of algorithms to solve minimization problems. There is no "general approach".

Comment: @AnderBiguri I have found a sample code, but could you kindly help me how to use it in this case? [link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22494-conjugate-gradient-method/content/conjgrad.m)

Comment: @AnderBiguri  in optimization problems we have Ax=b. how to connect this to the above problem?

Comment: @AnderBiguri in the paper:[link](http://grail.cs.washington.edu/projects/gradientshop/demos/gs_paper_TOG_2009.pdf) in part 3 and 3.1,equation (2), (3) and (4 )which ist exactly want I would like to do. They have used "conjugated gradient". I googled it, but I didn't get it and didn't found a sample code to solve the objective problem. I have computed gradient of images using canny edge detector. another problem in solving optimization problem is defining the domain of Î. is this domain that [0,255] values for each pixel or something else? how I can solve this problem using conjugate gradient?

Comment: I know that for example in deblurring problem we have; [blurred image] * x = [original image] that for solving we would have e.g. A = rand(256)*256; B = rand(256)*256; x = B./A;  but the problem is what about the problem mentioned in the paper? in that case A x b what would be?

Comment: Conjugate gradient is only one method. The minimization problem you state can also be solved with other methods. Since you use Matlab, [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/) might be helpful, there is a [MOOC](https://lagunita.stanford.edu/courses/Engineering/CVX101/Winter2014/about) that can educate you on how to use it, it is free for academic users. In Python, [CVXOPT](http://cvxopt.org/) might be useful. But keep in mind that optimization is not a trivial subject, you will probably have to learn a thing or two (or more).

Comment: @SamvanHerwaarden considering the paper link which I put in the question. I wanted to solve it using this method as first experience. but the problem is I don't know how to get A,x and b to feed the method by .